# JSON_TABLE not working in the MariaDB 10.6

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to run the query on MySql 8 which executed the query and returned the result as expected: https://share.bsf.io/mXuY7D7G

Whereas the same query failing on MariaDB 10.6 with #1064 Error: https://share.bsf.io/p9u6zeww

When I researched in MariaDB doc, it clearly supported JSON_TABLE: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/

I am using the following charset

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe MariaDB and MySQL have implemented their support of JSON independently, since MariaDB forked from MySQL. They both have a function named `JSON_TABLE()` but their internal code and data structures are different, so there will inevitably be small differences in the behavior. You should not think of MariaDB and MySQL as compatible anymore. Their differences will continue to widen as time goes on.

Comment: Plase don't upload oimeages see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and for a [mre] it helps also to have some data with the query

Comment: besides update your server as the newer version have tweaked it a lot

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b2a6faab58240dd60ecbb2235f7bca78).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring with MariaDB 10.4 and below, it resolved when updated a version to the latest one that is 10.8.

Thank you!

Comment: [JSON_TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) was only added in 10.6

Answer (score 0):

JSON_TABLE was added in MariaDB 10.6.0.